# Python 3: How to check if file is open? Python equivalent of C++ ifstream.is_open() function?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, file-io

How do I check if a file has been opened correctly after opening the file in Python3?

```
with open("filename" as f:
    # check that file is opened correctly here
```

C++ `ifstream` provides the `is_open()` function for this purpose. Is there a Python equivalent of the C++ `ifstream::is_open()` function?

In C one would do

```
FILE *fd = fopen(...)
if(fd != NULL) ...
```

Comment: Try ```if not f.closed: print("File is open")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open('file.txt')
if f.closed:
  print 'file is closed'
if not f.closed:
      print 'file is opened'
```

Comment: Ah yes, so simple, yet to difficult to find in the documentation